# REGEX, get text and character across multiple lines

Tags: regex

I would like to get to

```
    await ƒS.Speech.tell(
      characters.narrator,
      "Some text here"
    );
    await ƒS.Speech.tell(characters.anothername, "Some other text"
    );
```

via REGEX the following

```
characters.narrator, "Some text here"
characters.anothername, "Some other text"
```

However, so far I have only been able to get the text between the quotes via

```
"(.*?)"
```

How could the REGEX be extended to get that?

Answer (score 1):

You could extend the pattern like:

```
\w+(?:\.\w+)+,\s+"[^"]*"
```

**Explanation**

- `\w+` Match 1+ word chars
- `(?:\.\w+)+` Repeat 1+ times matching `.` and again 1+ word chars
- `,\s+` Match a comma and 1+ whitspace chars (that can also match a newline)
- `"[^"]*"` Match `"..."`

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/dBaxDV/1).